# Increase I2C-Speed with Hyperpixel 4.0 mounted

Tags: i2c, touchscreen, pi-3a+, dbus

i hava a Hyperpixel 4.0 mounted on my Raspberry Pi 3A+. Because of the Pin overlay for the Hyperpixel 4.0, the I2C bus is not Standard and is created on the Physical Pins 19 and 23 on my Raspberry. (I use i2cdetect -y 11 to detect a I2C device). Because the I2C bus is not on the standard Pins, i dont know how to increase the I2C Bus-Speed. Can anyone help me? I would really like to have 400kHz clock frequency than the Standard 100kHz.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in trying to increase the Pi's software I2C bus speed.

The I2C bus you are using is implemented in software.  It will not be able to keep up with a higher bus speed.  Personally I doubt it actually reaches 100 kbps.

If you need higher speeds you need to be using the hardware I2C bus on GPIO 2/3 (pins 3/5).